# With 2 sets of strings, find a string that can be constructed from either set

Tags: java, strings, array

Given the following sets of strings:

```
are yo
you u
how nhoware
alan arala
dear de
```

I need to find a sequence that can be constructed by concatenating the strings in either columnm, and it must use the same number of elements in both cases.

For example, **"dearalanhowareyou"** can be constructed from both sets of strings, using 5 elements each time.

A invalid choice would be **"dearalanhoware"** since it would use 4 elements from the left column but only 3 from the right

The problem is taken from here:

https://open.kattis.com/problems/correspondence

I'm using this site to improve for future job interviews and I just can't seem to figure this one out at all.

My only working implementation is a brute force approach taking every possible combination of each set which is not a very good solution due to time complexity.

My code right now:

```
 list1 = getPermutations("",send1);
            list2 = getPermutations("",send2);

     ArrayList<String> duplicateValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
                if (list2.contains(list1.get(i))) {
                    duplicateValues.add(list1.get(i));
                }

    private static ArrayList<String> getPermutations(String currentResult, ArrayList<String> possibleChars) {
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(possibleChars.size());
            for (String append : possibleChars) {
                String permutation = currentResult + append; 



                result.add(permutation); 
                if (possibleChars.size() > 0) {

                    ArrayList<String> possibleCharsUpdated = (ArrayList) possibleChars.clone();

                    possibleCharsUpdated.remove(new String(append));

                    result.addAll(getPermutations(permutation, possibleCharsUpdated));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42357711/6461941) to your question from regular stack exchange website.

Comment: You're trying to solve "Post's Correspondence Problem", which is known to be undecidable. Long story short: it's going to be **really** hard to get this to be remotely fast...